# Does discovery of graviton disprove wormhole since latter is applicable in GR only?

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-gravity, wormholes, carrier-particles

I know graviton is only a hypothetical particle invented probably to serve as a placeholder in standard model, but suppose one day we discovered graviton, does this disprove the existence of wormhole which is one of the solution that pop up in general relativity math?

Comment: It does not disprove wormholes. There is no connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem as long as quantized gravity is still effective, and probably even if it is definitely quantized. As in this [publication's](https://inspirehep.net/files/1fa811f248b9833ec127aabcdf593760) abstract.

> We investigate the effect of wormholes on gravitons. We obtain the two-point function for gravitons in asymptotically flat space in the presence of a wormhole. We show that this result can be reproduced in the theory of gravitons in flat space by the first-order contribution to the propagator due to an effective interaction of the form $C_{μνρσ} C^{μνρσ}$ . In the linear approximation to pure gravity there are no wormhole-induced corrections to the cosmological constant or to Newton's constant.